# Problemas al publicar una pagina en mvc 5 en IIS 7

Tags: c#, mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, iis, windows-server

Tengo una pagina que realice en mvc 5 de .NET con el framework 4.6.1 , y la estoy intentando publicar en un servidor Windows Web Server 2008 Service Pack 2 con un IIS 7 pero no me deja visualizar la pagina me aparece un :

> HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden The Web server is configured to not list
>   the contents of this directory
>   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Indiferentemente de usar http o https

Configuración del IIS
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: porque veo que solo pones `localhost` no creas un website con un puerto para este sitio ? ademas pones `talleres2` o sea quiere decir que creas un virtual directory ?

Comment: el sitio lo nombre talleres2 y solo coloco localhost ya por defecto le deje el puerto 80.No estoy creando un directorio virtual.

Comment: si creaste un sitio talleres2 entonces no va en el puerto 80, creo que confundes conceptos, un sitio tiene su propio puerto. podrias poner una imagen de como tienes configurado el iis ?

Comment: Listo ya las subi